# In autocomplete from materials ui how can I can click a button and clear the autocomplete like make it empty

Tags: reactjs

The autocomplete looks like this

```
<Autocomplete options={speceificLocation.locationOptions} onChange = {(event,value) => (speceificLocation.locationOptions.includes(value)) ? dispatch({allCities:state.allCities, mappedCities:true}):dispatch({allCities:state.allCities,  mappedCities:false})} renderInput = {(params) => <TextField {...params}  label = 'Cities'/>}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a live demo of an `Autocomplete` that can be cleared by a button.

[image: Edit ControllableStates Material Demo (forked)]

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

const options = ["Option 1", "Option 2"];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string | null>(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : "null"}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Button onClick={() => setValue("")}>Clear</Button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: string | null) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```